# Hadoop MapReduce: Processing all element combinations in Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, combinations, reduction

I am trying to use MR job to solve the following problem.
I have a huge table 'Fields' in Hive, containing info about users collected from several SQL DBs. Records in this table has the following format:

```
user_id, db_name, table_name, field_name, field_value
```

I am trying to build all possible pairs of users that have one or more values equal for these users in some of their fields. 
For example, with the following records in table 'Fields':

```
user_id = 10021, db_name = "db1", table_name = "contacts",  field_name = "phone", field_value = "613 5246 2433"
user_id = 10021, db_name = "db1", table_name = "contacts",  field_name = "user_mail",  field_value = "john@foobar.com"
user_id = 10021, db_name = "db1", table_name = "contacts",  field_name = "addres", field_value = "21,Sunset Beach" 
...
user_id = 37756, db_name = "db2", table_name = "user_info", field_name = "mobile", field_value = "613 5246 2433"
user_id = 37756, db_name = "db2", table_name = "user_info", field_name = "wrk_email", field_value = "john@foobar.com"
user_id = 37756, db_name = "db2", table_name = "user_info", field_name = "wrk_addr", field_value = "15, Circus Drive"
```

In this case I need to build the folowing records describing a pair of `matching` users:

```
user_1 = 10021, user_2 =37756, field_1 = "user_mail", field_2 = "wrk_email", value =  "john@foobar.com"
user_1 = 10021, user_2 =37756, field_1 = "phone", field_2 = "mobile", value = "613 5246 2433"
```

To achieve these my mapper function reads records from huge 'Fields' table in Hive. For each record a I create a key-value pair: (key = field_value, value = FieldInfo), where FieldInfo contains the remaining fields from this record (user_id, db_name, table_name, field_name, field_value).

As a result reducer function gets a very long stream of FiledInfo objects associated with a key equal to a specific filed value. To build `pair` records from this stream, I need to find all  combinations of any two `user_id`-s contained in thsese FiledInfo objects.

So for example, for a field value `john@foobar.com` I may get several thousands of FiledInfo elements with distinct `user_id`-s. Which means I need to build several thousands cominations of two ids. To build these pairs I need to be able to iterate all, lets say N  elements N! times.

I can only move forward along a stream that reducer provides, so I tried  to write this stream into a linked List. As it turned out, with this approach I run out of memory quite soon.

Any other ideas how to build combinations from a very long stream that reducer provides? Maybe I need to use entirely different approach for this task, other ideas for mapper and reducer functions?

Thanks!

Any comments at all?